# JFET Source follower input impedance

Tags: jfet

I want to derive the input impedance of this JFET circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlZJG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is the method in order to derive the input impedance of this circuit?

here is the small signal but I haven't been able to deduce the equation of the input impedance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd0U8r.png)</sup>

by neglecting output load :

Zi=Vin/i

i=(Vgs+gm*Vgs*R3)/R1

Vin=Vgs*(1+gm*R3+gm*R4)+i*R4 = Vgs*(1+gm*R3+gm*R4)+(Vgs+gm*Vgs*R3)/R1*R4

Zi=((1+gm*R3+gm*R4)+(1+gm*R3)/R1*R4)/((1+gm*R3)/R1)

There is something wrong with these equations but I can't see my mistake...

Comment: Here you will find the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372071/r-in-and-r-out-mosfet-calrification/372094#372094

Comment: You have to draw the equivalent circuit for incremental signals at the center of the band . Once this is done, analyze the circuit and find the input impedance by applying a test voltage source to the input.

Comment: "derivate" is a result of a calculation. I believe you want to "derive" the input impedance. Have you thought about using a simulation tool?

Comment: We see that R1 resistor current determines the Rin. Rin = Vin/I_R1 So we need to find the I1 resistor current. JFET gate current is 0A. So I_R1 current is:  $$I_1 = \frac{V_{IN} - V_{OUT}\frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4}}{R_1}$$ Additionally, we know that \$V_{OUT} = A_V * V_{IN}\$ So if we combine all the information we get Zin is equal to $$Z_{IN} = \frac{R_1}{1 - A_V \times \frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4}}$$

Comment: I see that you did manage to find the Zin. Your equation is correct. Good job.

Comment: This technique of increasing Zinc is called bootstrapping.  Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586839/explanation-about-op-amp-bias-resistor-and-bootstrapping/586859#586859. And in your circuit, we have the same situation.  But this time Zin ≈ R1/(1 - Av * R4/(R3 + R4)) where  Av ≈ ((R3 + R4)||RL)/( 1/gm + (R3 + R4)||RL)

Comment: G36, thanks for your explanations, I didn't know that feedback was called bootstraping.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the input impedance as suggested in the links in the comments. Deriving a useful function over frequency is more involved, thus, using a simulator is a more expedient method. The accuracy of the simulation depends on the accuracy of the transistor model.

The simulation below shows how you can do this in LTspice.
[image]

The red trace is the input capacitance which is about 2.1 pF which affects the impedance (|Z|) above 5 kHz.

Comment: qrk Thanks a lot for your reply, you're right the result is 6Mohms but I can't find it by equation from my small signal model

Comment: See the update in the first post for equations and small signal model